# Why callbacks in react functional component is not reading the updated state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement infinite scroller using intersection observer in react but the problem i am facing is that in the callback of intersection observer i am not able to read latest value of current 'page' and the 'list' so that i can fetch data for next page.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
require("intersection-observer");

const pageSize = 30;
const threshold = 5;

const generateList = (page, size) => {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    arr.push(`${(page - 1) * size + i}`);
  }

  return arr;
};

const fetchList = page => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve(generateList(page, pageSize));
    }, 1000);
  });
};

let options = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0
};

function App() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(false);
  const [list, setlist] = useState(generateList(page, pageSize));

  const callback = entries => {
    if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
      observerRef.current.unobserve(
        document.getElementById(`item_${list.length - threshold}`)
      );
      setFetching(true);
/* at this point neither the 'page' is latest nor the 'list'
*they both have the initial states.
*/
      fetchList(page + 1).then(res => {
        setFetching(false);
        setPage(page + 1);
        setlist([...list, ...res]);
      });
    }
  };

  const observerRef = useRef(new IntersectionObserver(callback, options));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (observerRef.current) {
      observerRef.current.observe(
        document.getElementById(`item_${list.length - threshold}`)
      );
    }
  }, [list]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {list.map(l => (
        <p key={l} id={`item_${l}`}>
          {l}
        </p>
      ))}
      {fetching && <p>loading...</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**current behaviour:** value of 'page' and 'list' is always equals to the initial state and not the latest value. Infinite scroll is not working after page 2

**expected behaviour:** In callback function it should read updated value of state 'page' and 'list'.

Here is the working sandbox of this **demo** https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-sun-rbcml?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Instead of `observerRef.current = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);`, How about `observerRef.current = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => callback(entries, page, fetching, list), options);` and update the `callback` method signature accordingly? (set methods are fine, only values to be include as args)

Comment: It didn't make any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are primary two problems here, closures and querying the DOM directly.

To solve the closures problem, use functional `useState` and references:

```
const listLengthRef = useRef(list.length);
const pageRef = useRef(page);

const callback = useCallback(entries => {
  if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
    observerRef.current.unobserve(
      document.getElementById(`item_${listLengthRef.current - threshold}`)
    );
    setFetching(true);
    fetchList(pageRef.current + 1).then(res => {
      setFetching(false);
      setPage(page => page + 1);
      setlist(list => [...list, ...res]);
    });
  }
}, []);

const observerRef = useRef(new IntersectionObserver(callback, options));

useEffect(() => {
  listLengthRef.current = list.length;
}, [list]);

useEffect(() => {
  pageRef.current = page;
}, [page]);
```

Although this code works, you should replace `document.getElementById` with reference, in this case, it will be a reference to the last element of the page.

[image: Edit frosty-smoke-if4il]

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the React `setState` [callback method](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to guarantee that you will receive the previous value.

Update your `callback` function as the following and it should work.

```
const callback = entries => {
  if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
    setFetching(true);
    setPage(prevPage => {
      fetchList(prevPage + 1).then(res => {
        setFetching(false);
        setlist(prevList => {
          observerRef.current.unobserve(document.getElementById(`item_${prevList.length - threshold}`));
          return ([...prevList, ...res]);
        });
      })
      return prevPage + 1;
    })
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to the ref keeps reference to the old observer. you need to refresh observer everytime your dependencies gets updated. it relates to closure in js. I would update your app to move the callback inside useEffect

```
function App() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(false);
  const [list, setlist] = useState(generateList(page, pageSize));


  const observerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const callback = entries => {
      if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
        observerRef.current.unobserve(
          document.getElementById(`item_${list.length - threshold}`)
        );
        setFetching(true);
    /* at this point neither the 'page' is latest nor the 'list'
     *they both have the initial states.
     */
        console.log(page, list);
        fetchList(page + 1).then(res => {
          setFetching(false);
          setPage(page + 1);
          setlist([...list, ...res]);
        });
      }
    };
    observerRef.current = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

    if (observerRef.current) {
      observerRef.current.observe(
        document.getElementById(`item_${list.length - threshold}`)
      );    
    }
  }, [list]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {list.map(l => (
        <p key={l} id={`item_${l}`}>
          {l}
        </p>
      ))}
      {fetching && <p>loading...</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```